# Google Domains and Google Cloud Platform

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, dns, ssl-certificate

I started a project with Google Cloud, I linked my Google Domain to the project. I then changed the Google Name Servers at the Domains site. My website is through Wordpress which I linked through the Google Cloud marketplace. I then used WordPresses ssl certificate generating tool (Let's Encrypt) but was unable to generate the ssl certificate. Receiving error, AH00526 error on line 47 of /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf
I've tried to fix the problem but unable. I contacted Google Cloud (they say everything is working fine) I contacted Google Domains they say everything is configured correctly.
The bottom line is:
If I delete or terminate the project with Google Cloud, will I still be able to use the Google Domain to start another project from scratch?

Comment: Google Domains is not tied to Google Cloud Platform. If you have a domain name registered with Google Domains (the Registrar), you can point your Name Servers (NS) to any DNS server you want. Most likely you have your Registrar and DNS Server records incorrectly configured, or you did not wait long enough after changing them. The solution is in details that are not present in your post.

Comment: @John Hanley, my real question is, if I delete my VM Instance can I start another VM Instance from scratch and still use the same domain name? I won't lose my domain or my website that my domain points towards right?

Comment: If you delete your VM, you will lose your website until you configure a new VM and change the DNS settings for your domain name to point to the new VM. Typically, 24 to 72 hours unless you are using a static public IP address for your VM which you can then move from one VM to another in the same region. See Serhi Rohoza's answer for more infomration.

Answer (score 2):

[Google Domains](https://domains.google/) is an internet domain name registration service offered by Google. Google Domains offers domain registration, DNS hosting, DNSSEC, Dynamic DNS, domain forwarding, and email forwarding.

[Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/), offered by Google, is a suite of cloud computing services that runs on the same infrastructure that Google uses internally for its end-user products, such as Google Search, Gmail and YouTube.

As you can see, Google Domains and Google Cloud Platform are separated services served for different purposes.

If you delete your VM instance, you won't lose your domain and you'll be able to use your domain with another VM instance. If your domain points to the website configured at the VM instance you'd like to delete, you should save all of your data from the VM instance before deleting it. In addition, I'd recommend you to reserve and use a [static external IP address](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address) for your VM instance where your website will be configured.

Comment: Thank you, gentlemen I was able to delete the vm instance and create a new working instance. Everything seems to be working now. Once again thank you. Working on setting up MX records to receive email from my G Suite account.

Comment: Thank you for your confirmation, please accept my answer if it was helpful.